# Is it possible to use ASP.NET Core Identity (cookie based) for securing WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I think I'm having a little misconception that

`Identity = only MVC - returning Views`

and`WebAPI => you gotta go for token-ish way of authentication like JWT`

So, I'd want to ask

`Is it possible to use that default AspNetCore's Identity with WebAPI?`

Or maybe I should ask `Is javascript post/get attaching Cookies to it?`

Comment: No, you can use ASP.NET Core Identity but you should use JWT instead of Cookies

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why?

Comment: Because a Web API should not care what the client is, and you have to hack stuff to make cookies work either in JavaScript or in mobile apps

Comment: Add not to mention cookies expose your api to XSRF attacks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Some JS libraries require you to enable the passing of cookies, though. Axios, for example, requires you to set withCredentials: true.

Comment: Does it require to do something additional in compare to "normal" MVC when it comes to setting up that auth on backend?

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view Cookie is just a http header just like the Authorization header, so you can protect your API with cookie.

As a matter of fact if your API is just serving a SPA on the same domain, cookie is a better and safer option.

Token base authentication is for scenarios where an API is serving multiple clients on different domains with different access levels. It makes sense to separate the authentication server from API server in those cases.

I recommend reading these articles:

[Be careful of the JWT hype train](https://dev.to/darraghor/be-careful-of-the-jwt-hype-train-3e81)

[Please Stop Using Local Storage](https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either cookie authentication or token based authentication and even both if you want. It depends on your needs.

In javascript you can send both cookies and authorization headers to authorize.

Comment: Using JWT is not close at all to using OAuth

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So what? You can use JWT as well as OAuth.

Comment: What makes you think using Tokens is similar to OAuth? OAuth can be used with tokens or cookies as you see fit, that point makes no sense at all

Comment: @Alexander can you share any example to work together, cookie authentication and token both work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use that default AspNetCore's Identity with WebAPI?

Yes. It will work very similar like it works in the default `Asp.Net Mvc` template.  Your `AccountController` may look like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string login, string password)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login, password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        { 
            //process successful result
        }
        else
        {
            //process failed result
        }
    }
}
```

`SignInManager<>.PasswordSignInAsync()` will assign necessary cookies to process authentication.